# Using 2D Array to track value across rows and columns to the first occurrence of the value?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I searched around for something like this but couldn't find anything. Also struggled with the wording of my question so bear with me here. I'm working with data provided in an excel file and have excel/VBA and python available to use. I'm still learning both and I just need a push in the right direction on what method to use so I can work through it and learn.

Say I have a series of 5 processes in a manufacturing facility, each process represented by a column. Occasionally a downstream process (column 5) gets backed up and slows down upstream processes (column 4, then 3, etc). I have a 2D array that indicates running(0) or backed up(1). Each column is an individual process and each row is a time interval. The array will be the same size every time (10000+ rows, 5 columns), but the values change. Example:

```
MyArray = [0 0 0 0 0
           0 1 0 0 0
           1 1 0 0 1
           1 0 0 0 1
           0 0 0 1 1
           0 0 1 1 1
           0 0 1 1 0
           0 1 1 0 0
           0 1 0 0 0
           0 0 0 0 0]
```

Essentially when there is a value of 1, I want to trace it to the upper rightmost adjacent 1. So for column 1, rows 2 & 3 would be traced back to column 2, row 2. For column 2, rows 8 & 9 would be traced back to column 5, row 3. Currently I have just have an if statement looking to the right within the same row and it's better than nothing, but does not capture the cascade effect you get when something backs up multiple upstream processes.

I could figure out a way to do it by looping a search to look up in a column until it finds a zero, then if the next column value is a 1, search up until finds a zero, repeat. But this seems really inefficient and I feel like there has to be a better way to do it. Any kinds of thoughts or comments would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One tip is to actually begin from the bottom row (let's call this row r=0) and first column c=1 and search rightward until you hit column c=5. If no 1s are found then repeat the search for the second-to-bottom row, and continue until you search the top row.

Whenever a 1 is found at some index (r, c), recursively ask the question "does this element have all zeros above (r+1, c), to the right (r, c+1), or above and to the right (r+1, c+1). Now, I'm not sure what you do in the case of a "tie", i.e. when there is a 1 above, at (r+1, c), and another 1 to the right, at (r, c+1), but a 0 at (r+1, c+1), but you could address this competition in a simple if statement.

Comment: P.S. I'm happy to discuss/ edit my answer to make things more clear or specific!

Comment: That's the way I was looking at doing it currently unless there's a smarter/faster/more efficient way to do it. I'm not too concerned about a tie like that considering the way the array is filled in handles those already and if a couple slip in, it doesn't significantly affect it as a whole. Appreciate the input!

Comment: I see. I'm not sure that there are any optimizations to be made since you have to traverse the entire 2D array to "know" that you've achieved the upper right most 1 for each sequence.